# $\dim V/ (S_{1}\cap S_{2})$ when $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ have finite codimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Exercise 13 from Roman's book "Advanced Linear Algebra" (page 107).

The author gives us a vector space $V$ with $$V=S_{1}\oplus T_{1}=S_{2}\oplus T_{2}$$ and asks us to prove that if $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ have finite codimension in $V$, then so does 
$\dim V/ (S_{1}\cap S_{2})$ and $$\dim V/ (S_{1}\cap S_{2})\leq \dim T_{1}+\dim T_{2}.$$

I did a lot of work but I didn't get anywhere.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p_1\colon V \to T_1$ and $p_2\colon V \to T_2$ be the projections coming with the direct sums. What are the kernels of these maps? If you define a map
\[
V \to T_1 \times T_2
\]
by sending $x$ to $(p_1(x), p_2(x))$, then what is the kernel of this?